# python - How to plot data with repeating x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot day dependent data over many years where years should be on the x-axis (2016,2017,2018 for example). What is a good approach to do this?

For every year I have a list of days which I would plot on the x-axis but of course python keeps this axis and plots all the data of different years above each other.

Any suggestions?

Code:

A shortened version of my dictionary  `L_B_1_mean` looks like this:

```
2016018 5.68701407589
2016002 4.72437644462
2017018 3.39389424822
2018034 7.01093439059
2018002 8.79958946488
2017002 3.55897852367
```

the code:

```
data_plot = {"x":[], "y":[], "label":[]}
for label, coord in L_B_1_mean.items():
    data_plot["x"].append(int(label[-3:]))             
    data_plot["y"].append(coord)
    data_plot["label"].append(label)


# add labels
for label, x, y in zip(data_plot["label"], data_plot["x"], data_plot["y"]):
    axes[1].annotate(label, xy = (x, y+0.02), ha= "left")


# 1 channel different years Plot
plt_data = axes[1].scatter(data_plot["x"], data_plot["y"])
```

I construct my x-values here: `data_plot["x"].append(int(label[-3:]))` where I read the name tag like: 2016002 and get only the day value: 002

In the end I have 365 days per year and now i would like to plot the data of 2016 then 2017 and then 2018 all after each other instead of on top of each other

Comment: Hi @Shaun, could you please post what you have tried so far? And could you please add example data to your code so that it's easier for people to help you out? Your question looks now a bit too broad to get a good answer...

Comment: @toti08 hmm ok...i thought it's more like a conceptual question if there's a way to repeat the x-axis and assign data to it. But I'll add some code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a dict

```
L_B_1_mean 

{'2016018': 5.68701407589,
 '2016002': 4.72437644462,
 '2017018': 3.39389424822,
 '2018034': 7.010934390589999,
 '2018002': 8.79958946488,
 '2017002': 3.55897852367}
```

**plot using pandas:**

```
import pandas as pd
```

You can simply create a pandas series from this dict:

```
s = pd.Series(L_B_1_mean)

2016018    5.687014
2016002    4.724376
2017018    3.393894
2018034    7.010934
2018002    8.799589
2017002    3.558979
dtype: float64
```

...and cast the strings in the index to dates:

```
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index, format='%Y%j')

2016-01-18    5.687014
2016-01-02    4.724376
2017-01-18    3.393894
2018-02-03    7.010934
2018-01-02    8.799589
2017-01-02    3.558979
dtype: float64
```

Then you can plot your data easily:

```
s.plot(marker='o')
```

[image]

**plot using datetime and matplotlib:**

```
import datetime as DT
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = [DT.datetime.strptime(k, '%Y%j') for k in L_B_1_mean.keys()]
v = list(L_B_1_mean.values())

v = sorted(v, key=lambda x: t[v.index(x)])
t = sorted(t)

plt.plot(t, v, 'b-o')
```

Comment: this is a very nice way of plotting the data. L_B_1 is a dictionary so i get this: AttributeError: `'dict' object has no attribute 'yearday'`. Also my code does plot the data as well. However i would like to have all the data of 2016 over 365 days and then over new 365 days data of 2017 etc... I think your code is ploting the same as mine :) and isn't quite what i'm looking for.

Comment: I nearly thought that it would come like this, as I did not perfectly unerstand which variant you have and which you want to achieve. And The fact that you have a dict was also not in my mind - sorry... I'll edit...